# How to open an external hard drive when its detected by Disk Utility but not in Finder?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have a microSD card that is working on my dashcam. But not mac. (latest Big Sur)

It's seeable in the Disk Utility but not in Finder.

What should I do?

[image]

Update:

```
aab-MacBook-Pro-2:~ myname$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *63.0 GB    disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS ⁨⁩                        62.9 GB    disk2s1
aab-MacBook-Pro-2:~ myname$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk2
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 7655/255/63 [122978304 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
*1: 07    2  10   9 - 1023 254  63 [     32768 -  122945536] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: Edit your post and add the output from the commands `diskutil list disk2` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk2`.

Comment: updated. btw, I can open it and access my files in the folder by inputting the path `/Volume/....` in the folder's "Go to" box. but still can't see the icon in the Folder App sidebar.

Comment: I think that's because its untitled. In Disk utility hit the view icon, then show all devices and try to rename the partition. Does that work?

Comment: Generally, your problem occurs when the volume is mounted with the `nobrowse` option. What does the output from `mount | grep disk2` show?